# Recommendations for a cloud/hosted server environment that can run different Windows VMs?

Tags: windows, hosting, virtual-machines, cloud-hosting

I currently have a colocated Win 2008 server that I use for hosting different windows VMs for testing: Win 2008, Win XP, Vista, Win7, Win 2000. I'd like to ditch the server and use something like Amazon AWS but the key thing is I need to be able to launch VMs for these different windows versions. AWS doesn't allow this currently. Can anyone recommend somewhere that I could use?

The main reasons I want to get away from my own server are:

- administration: backup, windows updates, etc
- space: disk limitations mean I can't have all the VMs I want. I'd like to be able to pay for space incrementally. I'll typically only run 1-3 at a time but want lots of snapshots of different machines.

Comment: If you are looking for something that is both fully managed (for reduced administration) but also provides full administrative access, I will be very interested to see what you find.  I am accustomed to getting either one or the other, but not both.

Answer (score 1):

I would try a provider from [this page](http://www.vmware.com/solutions/cloud-computing/public-cloud/vcloud-express.html), or [this page](http://www.vmware.com/solutions/cloud-computing/public-cloud/vcloud-datacenter-services-providers.html).

Any one of those providers should be able to help you. I know for a fact [Bluelock](http://www.bluelock.com/) will do it, but I'll throw in a big disclaimer that *I work there*. :D

Answer (score 0):

An ad that displayed above my question pointed me to http://cloudsigma.com/ which look like they fit the bill too.